# Netbeans compile error, why does it mean?

Tags: netbeans, ant, compilation

I finished a Netbeans project a few months ago, it was successfully done, finished. But the strange thing is today I happen to look into it and recompiled it, haven't changed anything, but got the following error, I vaguely remember I encountered similar situations before, just recompile and it will be fine, but not this time, I recompiled a few times, same error, restarted the PC, and recompiled again, same error :

```
build-impl.xml:501: copylibs doesn't support the "indexMetaInf" attribute
```

I never touched this file and have no idea why it worked fine, but failed this time, what's wrong and what's the fix ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that **the problem is in version of Ant and new Ant attribute `indexMetaInf`**.

I have the same problem and think it'll be worth to explain how I've got it.

### How to obtain the problem:

*I use NetBeans 6.8.*

Recently I installed *NetBeans 7.0*. Just for acquaintance with new features.

I accepted to use old **NB6.8** configuration, when **NB7.0** asked me on the first launch.

That was mistake!

So. I started **NB7.0** and my good old **NB6.8** projects were there, in the projects list.

The problem is that **NB7.0** not only imported my old projects in its projects list; but also
**changed `build-impl.xml` of those projects**.

And when I opened my projects in **NB6.8** and tryed to compile them, there was that error with "indexMetaInf".

### The essence of the problem:

In **NB6.8** the Ant 1.7.1 is used, by default. And it seems that **attribute "indexMetaInf" is only supported by 
latest versions of Ant** ([maybe starting with 1.8.x](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194110#c2)). That new version of Ant was installed with **NB7.0** and is used by **NB7.0** only.
**NB6.8** doesn't see it.

### How to fix the problem:

I updated `build-impl.xml` file from subversion and it fixed the problem.
In my previous version of build-impl.xml there was no `indexMetaInf`.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, fixed it by copying the file `org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar` from `[netbeans]\java\ant\extra` into the directory `myProject\lib\CopyLibs`

Answer (score 0):

Strange thing happened again, this time good. I had a backup DVD, from a few weeks ago, I copied the project back, now it's compiling fine again, seems to me the project somehow got corrupted, I did a C: drive defragmentation last week, could it somehow moved some files around and messed up a bit ? Anyhow, not a problem now.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you using?  I've had some odd errors like that on Unix due to trying to compile the project from the command line and having a older version of ant in my path.

Comment: Win Vista & 7, today I found bunch of other projects had the save problem, so I copied them back from my backup DVD and recompiled them , they work fine now. I definitely suspect the defragmentation, nothing else could systematically mess up so many files.